# Java beginner: How to get the the number of values from a user input string in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

User can enter as many numbers he can and the program should sort them all. So I want to find the number elements in the input before start sorting them. Example "Enter some numbers" Input: 76 24 56 9 312 1 3013 and I want output: 1 9 24 56 76 312 3013 (Ascending order). Note I didn't ask the user to enter how many he is gonna enter first, that is exactly what I want to know how to find.

Here is the working code with user enter the array size himself

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArraySorting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter size of the array");
        int z = in.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[z];
        System.out.println("Enter numbers");
        for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {
            a[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < z - 1; j++) {
            for (int p = 0; p < (z - 1) - j; p++) {
                if (a[p] > a[p + 1]) {
                    int n = a[p];
                    a[p] = a[p + 1];
                    a[p + 1] = n;
                }//if loop
            }//for loop 2
        }//for loop 1
        System.out.println("Numbers in Ascending order:");
        for (int k = 0; k < z; k++) {
            System.out.print(a[k] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `String[] numbers =String.split(" ");` this will split your String into an array of Strings at the blank spaces (they will get deleted)

Comment: Please "beautify" your code. It is very difficult to read ;)

Comment: You could just read whatever the users enters into a List and check it's size.

Comment: " Note I didn't ask the user to enter how many he is gonna enter first, that is exactly what I want to know how to find" ... Your code actually does take the first input as length.

Comment: @Tom http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You can take input as comma separated numbers. Split it using comma, sort and print the output.

Instead of array use a List. User will keep on entering a number. If user enters "End" or "Finish" or something then you sort the list and print the output.

Answer (score 0):

Hit return after each number.

And for future PLEASE use meaningful variable names it helps a lot to read your code for other developers :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    boolean finished = false;

    System.out.println("Enter numbers.\nType End to finish");
    do {
        input = scanner.next();
        if (input.toLowerCase().equals("end")) {
            finished = true;
            Collections.sort(numbers);
            System.out.println(numbers);
            System.out.println("You have entered " + numbers.size() + " numbers");
        } else {
            try {
                numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(input));
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("This is not a number please try again !");
            }
        }
    } while (!finished);

}
```